# Why is my list being populated twice for every entry instead of once?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a login system with VBA. I took a look at the PasswordBook file from here: https://www.ozgrid.com/download/ and it works really well for what I need. I added my own usernames and passwords and was even able to get it to record the time a user logs in as well.

My issue is that I want to modify it a bit to create a history to see who has been logging in. I made a second sheet in the workbook with a table to keep track of this. When I log in, it writes to the list in Sheet2 twice instead of just once.

I want the system to write to the next available line in the table to keep a neat record of who is logging in. I tried going the `IsEmpty()` route, but I couldn't make that work so I decided to use `WorksheetFunction.CountA` instead. It worked in the sense that it wrote to the next empty line, but it wrote to two lines instead of just one.

In Sheet1, I have this code to track the person and time they logged in.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Row = 2 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
      Cells(2, 5).Value = ""
    Else
      Cells(2, 5).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    End If
  End If

  Call Logger

End Sub
```

And in a module, I have this to write that data from Sheet1 to Sheet2:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Logger()

Dim LastRowUser As Long
Dim LastRowDate As Long
Dim NameInfo As String
Dim DateInfo As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

NameInfo = ws1.Range("D2")
DateInfo = ws1.Range("E2")
LastRowUser = ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
LastRowDate = ws2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B2:B32")) = 0 Then
    ws2.Range("B" & LastRowUser).Value = NameInfo
End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C2:C32")) = 0 Then
    ws2.Range("C" & LastRowDate).Value = DateInfo
End If

End Sub
```

I feel like it's something simple staring me in the face, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Also, if the user and date information are always associated, why track two different variables for the next row? You can just use one variable and offset columns for the date.

Comment: Need to move line `Call Logger` inside your Outer `If` statement in the `Worksheet_Change` code.